# Is It possible to set PHP session variables inside Angular JS

Tags: php, angularjs

I need to set a PHP Session variables, inside an Angular JS Script, because if I try to pass an angualr variables inside a php one, I will get lots of error and problems... So, Is there any way to archive this ?

```
<?php
   $placeBean = "{{masterCtrl.getLastplace();}}";
   $manualPlaceBean = 6;
?>
```

If I wrote this, the variables, is correctly setted inside $placeBean, if I try to pass it in a php function, it won't works, but if I manually set $placeBean, as the value of masterCtrl.getLastplace(), all will works.

An other thing, I noticed is that if I var_dump the two variables, I got different output (same text, different lenght), while if I do the echo of the $placeBean  and $manualPlaceBean, I got the same value.
If I do the addcslashes($placeBean,'A..z'), I will get this : {{\m\a\s\t\e\r\C\t\r\l.\g\e\t\L\a\s\t\p\l\a\c\e();}}

EDIT 1

I wrote this 
//placeSession.php

```
<?php
  $buffer = $_POST['lastPlace'];
  $_SESSION['lastPlace'] = $buffer;
?>
```

//AngularController

```
app.factory('placeSession', function($resource) {

    var setData = function(place) {
        // Angular $http() and then() both return promises themselves
        return $resource('./PHP/session/placeSession.php').
               save({ lastPlace: place }).
               $promise.then(function(res) {
              console.log(res);
            }).catch(function (err) {
              console.log(err);
           });
    };

    return { setData: setData };
});
app.controller('PlaceController', function(placeSession) {
    this.saveSelection = function(value){
        placeSession.setData(value);
    }
});
```

res Output is :

> Resource {0: "C", 1: "i", 2: "a", 3: "o", 4: " ", 5: " ", 6: "<", 7:
>   "b", 8: "r", 9: " ", 10: "/", 11: ">", 12: "↵", 13: "<", 14: "b", 15:
>   ">", 16: "F", 17: "a", 18: "t", 19: "a", 20: "l", 21: " ", 22: "e",
>   23: "r", 24: "r", 25: "o", 26: "r", 27: "<", 28: "/", 29: "b", 30:
>   ">", 31: ":", 32: " ", 33: " ", 34: "U", 35: "n", 36: "c", 37: "a",
>   38: "u", 39: "g", 40: "h", 41: "t", 42: " ", 43: "E", 44: "r", 45:
>   "r", 46: "o", 47: "r", 48: ":", 49: " ", 50: "C", 51: "a", 52: "l",
>   53: "l", 54: " ", 55: "t", 56: "o", 57: " ", 58: "u", 59: "n", 60:
>   "d", 61: "e", 62: "f", 63: "i", 64: "n", 65: "e", 66: "d", 67: " ",
>   68: "f", 69: "u", 70: "n", 71: "c", 72: "t", 73: "i", 74: "o", 75:
>   "n", 76: " ", 77: "d", 78: "e", 79: "b", 80: "u", 81: "g", 82: "*",
>   83: "t", 84: "o", 85: "*", 86: "c", 87: "o", 88: "n", 89: "s", 90:
>   "o", 91: "l", 92: "e", 93: "(", 94: ")", 95: " ", 96: "i", 97: "n",
>   98: " ", 99: "D", …}0: "C"1: "i"2: "a"3: "o"4: " "5: " "6: "<"7: "b"8:
>   "r"9: " "10: "/"11: ">"12: "↵"13: "<"14: "b"15: ">"16: "F"17: "a"18:
>   "t"19: "a"20: "l"21: " "22: "e"23: "r"24: "r"25: "o"26: "r"27: "<"28:
>   "/"29: "b"30: ">"31: ":"32: " "33: " "34: "U"35: "n"36: "c"37: "a"38:
>   "u"39: "g"40: "h"41: "t"42: " "43: "E"44: "r"45: "r"46: "o"47: "r"48:
>   ":"49: " "50: "C"51: "a"52: "l"53: "l"54: " "55: "t"56: "o"57: " "58:
>   "u"59: "n"60: "d"61: "e"62: "f"63: "i"64: "n"65: "e"66: "d"67: " "68:
>   "f"69: "u"70: "n"71: "c"72: "t"73: "i"74: "o"75: "n"76: " "77: "d"78:
>   "e"79: "b"80: "u"81: "g"82: "*"83: "t"84: "o"85: "*"86: "c"87: "o"88:
>   "n"89: "s"90: "o"91: "l"92: "e"93: "("94: ")"95: " "96: "i"97: "n"98:
>   " "99: "D"100: ":"101: "\"102: "E"103: "a"104: "s"105: "y"106: "P"107:
>   "H"108: "P"109: "-"110: "D"111: "e"112: "v"113: "s"114: "e"115:
>   "r"116: "v"117: "e"118: "r"119: "-"120: "1"121: "7"122: "\"123:
>   "e"124: "d"125: "s"126: "-"127: "w"128: "w"129: "w"130: "\"131:
>   "a"132: "n"133: "g"134: "u"135: "l"136: "a"137: "r"138: "W"139:
>   "e"140: "b"141: "B"142: "o"143: "o"144: "k"145: "\"146: "P"147:
>   "H"148: "P"149: "\"150: "s"151: "e"152: "s"153: "s"154: "i"155:
>   "o"156: "n"157: "\"158: "p"159: "l"160: "a"161: "c"162: "e"163:
>   "S"164: "e"165: "s"166: "s"167: "i"168: "o"169: "n"170: "."171:
>   "p"172: "h"173: "p"174: ":"175: "5"176: "↵"177: "S"178: "t"179:
>   "a"180: "c"181: "k"182: " "183: "t"184: "r"185: "a"186: "c"187:
>   "e"188: ":"189: "↵"190: "#"191: "0"192: " "193: "{"194: "m"195:
>   "a"196: "i"197: "n"198: "}"199: "↵"200: " "201: " "202: "t"203:
>   "h"204: "r"205: "o"206: "w"207: "n"208: " "209: "i"210: "n"211: "
>   "212: "<"213: "b"214: ">"215: "D"216: ":"217: "\"218: "E"219: "a"220:
>   "s"221: "y"222: "P"223: "H"224: "P"225: "-"226: "D"227: "e"228:
>   "v"229: "s"230: "e"231: "r"232: "v"233: "e"234: "r"235: "-"236:
>   "1"237: "7"238: "\"239: "e"240: "d"241: "s"242: "-"243: "w"244:
>   "w"245: "w"246: "\"247: "a"248: "n"249: "g"250: "u"251: "l"252:
>   "a"253: "r"254: "W"255: "e"256: "b"257: "B"258: "o"259: "o"260:
>   "k"261: "\"262: "P"263: "H"264: "P"265: "\"266: "s"267: "e"268:
>   "s"269: "s"270: "i"271: "o"272: "n"273: "\"274: "p"275: "l"276:
>   "a"277: "c"278: "e"279: "S"280: "e"281: "s"282: "s"283: "i"284:
>   "o"285: "n"286: "."287: "p"288: "h"289: "p"290: "<"291: "/"292:
>   "b"293: ">"294: " "295: "o"296: "n"297: " "298: "l"299: "i"300:
>   "n"301: "e"302: " "303: "<"304: "b"305: ">"306: "5"307: "<"308:
>   "/"309: "b"310: ">"311: "<"312: "b"313: "r"314: " "315: "/"316:
>   ">"317: "↵"$promise: d {$$state: {…}}$resolved: true__proto__: Object

Comment: I sincerely hope not, otherwise it's an incredible security hole in an application

Comment: Angular is client side, PHP is server side. You have to post your variables to the server to let the PHP code do its thing. What errors are you getting?

Comment: If you already have some code, can you please post it?

Comment: I will post some code to explain better the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should make an ajax request to your server (on any php file) then you can set session or run whatever php codes you want and in return you can send the session value back.

Comment: `$http.get("http://example.com/file.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        you can use response in angular js
    });`

Comment: `http://example.com/file.php` in file.php, you can place your session codes into this file

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AngularJS `$resource`: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

You could easily POST to your PHP code with something like this:

```
$resource('/api/post-route/post.php')
    .save({ myData: true })
    .$promise
    .then(function (response) {
        // Do something with the response
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Handle error
    });
```

Obviously the route name in the initial call to `$resource` will be different, and the data you send will be also, but that's the basic pattern.  This is the only way to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: ok, so I will create a file called post.php, then in this file I can set the session variables?

Comment: Yes. The file can be called whatever you like. You may access `$_SESSION` and set whatever you need there this way for sure. You should be able to retrieve what you send via `$resource` in `$_POST`. Just be aware that you must include an additional library in your AngularJS app and add `ngResource` to the list of dependencies for your AngularJS module.

Comment: ok, but how will I pass the paramethers to set in the session ? for example... I have a variable this.number = 5; inside the angular controller... how can I set it in $_POST['selectedNumber']

Comment: Just replace `{ myData: true }` with `{ selectedNumber: this.number }`

Comment: I am trying to apply your method, but I am getting error on $resource(...).post is not a function

Comment: I use save, instead of post, and it seams to work, but I can't save the element  to session... is the code I wrote on answer correct ?

Comment: Sorry, you're correct `save` is the proper method. I've updated my answer. It does look correct. Does the callback passed to `then` get called? And is your PHP script bring run?

Comment: I think the php is not working, bacause, as I wrote in my updated answer, it seems not to works... but the then is called; infact I see the debug log in the console

Comment: If the callback is executed, it sounds like it reached your PHP file and got a successful response.  I'm not sure what you're doing with `$_SESSION` later, so it's hard to say based on the code if it's not working as intended. What happens if in your JavaScript you put the following call back in `then`: `function(res) { console.log(res); }` and also in your PHP code after setting `$_SESSION` you execute `echo json_encode($_SESSION);`? Do you see the users session printed in the browser console with the correct values?

Comment: I update the answer,  but can't see the echo json_encode($_SESSION)

Comment: The `save` method expects a JSON object in the response. It looks like it's getting a string with some HTML in it and converting it to a JavaScript object. Do you recognize the HTML being returned in this object?  I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot, if the only thing being echoed was the JSON encoded `$_SESSION` object, I don't think it would be in this form. Are you using a framework to handle request/response lifecycle, or plain PHP script?

Comment: How should I pass a (console printed) [object Object]  as  lastPlace

Comment: I think if you pass an object as `lastPlace` it should be serialized as JSON. You will likely need to decode it with `json_decode` in your PHP script.